Deploying firebase nextjs to vercel not working
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'email')
    at c (/vercel/path0/chat-firebase-next/client/.next/server/pages/ChatsPage.js:1:2385)
    at Wc (/vercel/path0/chat-firebase-next/client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (/vercel/path0/chat-firebase-next/client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/chat-firebase-next/client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at Zc (/vercel/path0/chat-firebase-next/client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/chat-firebase-next/client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at Zc (/vercel/path0/chat-firebase-next/client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/chat-firebase-next/client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at $c (/vercel/path0/chat-firebase-next/client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at bd (/vercel/path0/chat-firebase-next/client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
Error occurred prerendering page "/ChatsPage". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'email')
    at c (/vercel/path0/chat-firebase-next/client/.next/server/pages/ChatsPage.js:1:2385)
    at Wc (/vercel/path0/chat-firebase-next/client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (/vercel/path0/chat-firebase-next/client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/chat-firebase-next/client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at Zc (/vercel/path0/chat-firebase-next/client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/chat-firebase-next/client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at Zc (/vercel/path0/chat-firebase-next/client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/chat-firebase-next/client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at $c (/vercel/path0/chat-firebase-next/client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at bd (/vercel/path0/chat-firebase-next/client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
   Generating static pages (2/6) 
   Generating static pages (4/6) 

This is the error log
import { auth } from "@/firebase";
import { signOut, User } from "firebase/auth";
import { PrettyChatWindow } from "react-chat-engine-pretty";
interface ChatProps {
  user: User;
}



export default function Page(props: ChatProps) {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: "100vh" }}>
    <button
    style={{
      position: "absolute",
      top: "0px",
      left: "0px",
      backgroundColor: "#10a37f",
      border: "none",
      padding: ".5rem .75rem",
      color: "white",
      fontSize: ".875rem",
      borderRadius: ".25rem",
      cursor: "pointer",
      marginRight: "8px",
      boxShadow: "0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)",
    }}
      onClick={() => signOut(auth)}
    >
      Sign Out
    </button>
      <PrettyChatWindow
        projectId="32b58e76-3902-4cfe-a8cb-d6ddc210b648"
        username={props.user.email || "Guest"}
        secret={props.user.uid}
        style={{ height: "100%" }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

and this is my chats page
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^10.11.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^12.1.0",
    "next": "^14.2.1",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-chat-engine-pretty": "^0.1.8",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}


and this is my packge.json, i dont seem to understand the problem if someone experienced this recently or knows the fix i would greatly appreciate it. I keep trying to deploy, update my package.json, but it seems to be some sort of inline error, pretty new to vercel and nextjs
Trying to deploy but getting errors
